# Will Mac OSX 10.5.4 or 10.5.8 run on a PowerMac g5 quad?

Tags: powerpc, power-mac

I would like to know because I am going to get the highest version that will run on this specific Mac...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca), the latest version of Mac OS X any version of an Apple Power Mac G5 Desktop can take is Mac OS X 10.5.8 although Mac OS X 10.5.4 will also run on them.

The information I presented was what is reported by [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca) and they usually are correct with the information they provide.  In any case all sources I've looked at for the Power Mac G5 Quad 2.5GHz M9592LL/A PowerMac11,2 the only quad core Power Mac G5 produced all say the same thing, latest or maximum OS is "Mac OS X 10.5.8".  Unfourtunatly Apple's own page [Power Mac G5 (Late 2005) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP37?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) does not say. So I guess the answer should be contact Apple via phone or stop by an Apple store for what would be considered an authoritative source.

Comment: I heard a rumor that OSX 10.4.x is the highest one supported. So some variant of 10.4

Comment: You may have heard a rumor however the information I presented was what is reported by Mactracker and they usually are right.  In any case all sources I've looked at for the Power Mac G5 Quad 2.5GHz M9592LL/A PowerMac11,2 the only quad core Power Mac G5 produced all say the same thing, "Mac OS X 10.5.8".  Unfourtunatly Apple's own page [Power Mac G5 (Late 2005) - Technical Specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP37?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) does not say. So I guess the answer should be contact Apple via phone or stop by an Apple store for what would be considered an authoritative source.

Comment: Ok, still thank you I will double check the disk I am going to get on ebay and buy it sometime soon...

Comment: Also what the "rumor" you might be referring to may be for "MacOS 9 Support: Classic Mode Only* This model is capable of using Mac OS 9 applications within the Mac OS X "Classic" environment provided with Mac OS X 10.4.11 "Tiger" and lower ("Classic" is not supported starting with Mac OS X 10.5 "Leopard"). It cannot boot into Mac OS 9. "  from [Apple Power Macintosh G5 "Quad Core" (2.5) Specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g5/specs/powermac_g5_quad_2.5.html)

Comment: Sorry to bother... the mac OSX leopard  install disk 10.5.6 works too right? I'm assuming it does... it was the cheapest out of the bunch

Comment: It will if it was designed for that system or a retail copy.  If it's a grey and white disc those are machine specific, meaning they work on a subset of hardware combinations but not all of them.

Comment: I got ahold of apple they'll send me a disc for $16...